# how can i access a context of function view with a separate page in base page?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

i created newsletters app with below code after that i have a URL : subscribe that perfectly work and save my email after that i want to add  this ability in base page for example a user don't go to subscribe page and subscribed i want directly have access in base template and subscribe . 
i want to know this because i want add login form to base page and have this problem with that . 
this my code and this is my template 
tnx for help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def Subscribe(request):
    form = SiqnupNewslettersForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if SignupNewsletters.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            print("this email already taken ")
        else :
            instance.save()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }

    template_name = "subscribe.html"

    return render(request,template_name,context)


def Unsubcribe(request):
    form = SiqnupNewslettersForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if SignupNewsletters.objects.filter(email= instance.email).exists():
            SiqnupNewslettersForm.objects.filter(email = instance).delete()
        else:
            print("your email is not here")

        context = {
            'form' : form
        }
        template_name = "unsubscribe.html"

        return render(request,template_name,context)
```

subscribe.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="POST" action="">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form }}
           </div>
           <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" 
value="submit">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('subscribe/',views.Subscribe,name="subscribe"),
  path('unsubscribe/',views.Unsubcribe,name= "unsubscribe"),
]
```

and finally what i have to do for add newsletter form in base page ?

base.html

Comment: You probably have a view function for the base page. You can call the `subscribe` function from that view (`response = subscribe(request); context = response.context_data...`) or refactor to a common utility function to just return the `context` that you can re-use in both views. Also you can use `{% include ... %}` template tag to include an HTML snippet in both your base and subscribe.html templates.

Comment: @dirkgroten i will test that tnx for help me.