# How can I find my most expensive products?

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

On my product detail page I want to show the selected product and below that show my most expensive products.

How can I get my most expensive products? I'm trying to get something like this working:

```
product_detail_view = get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
most_expensive_products = Product.object.filter(price = ??????????) 
context { 'product_detail_view': product_detail_view ,
          'most_expensive_products':most_expensive_products }
return render (... )
```

What do I have to put in place of `?????????`?

Do I need to do this in my model itself?

Here's my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    car = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    tag = TaggableManager()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50,decimal_places=2)
    acitve = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timefield = 
    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. If you do that you'll find that you can be more focused and clear, which will help us understand and therefore respond with helpful information. See [ask].

Comment: @Chris sorry i fix my question . tnx for help me .

Comment: Are you asking how to find your most expensive products?

Comment: @Chris yes . i didn't know can i show two query and get two context something like up or i have to write a queryset in models.py if i set query set how can show in template.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your most expensive products by [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) your query and [slicing it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets):

```
Products.objects.order_by('-price')[:5]
```

Here we're ordering by `price` descending because of the `-` prefix. This query should give you your five most expensive `Product`s. Feel free to include other modifiers like `filter()` as well to get even more specific, e.g. to find the most expensive `Product`s in some category or to exclude the selected primary product from the list of most expensive ones.

Comment: it 's worked perfectly but i have a questions and don't want to create a new topic . i created this context in myapp.views and show query of that in template on this page detailview.html after i want this query show in another page and another app for example : root app and base.html page  how can i do that ?  how import that ? i created four days a go and ask something like that for newsletter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418335/how-can-i-access-a-context-of-function-view-with-a-separate-page-in-base-page